# Scrolling video in Chrome and Firefox drops frames over a certain resolution

Tags: javascript, html

It seems like a simple issue, but no amount of different encodes seem to fix this.

The page scrolls the currentTime of the video based on the scroll bar position:

http://akasemusic.com/vid/testvid.html

Does anyone know why this would be buggy in Chrome and Firefox, yet render perfectly in Safari?

Note: This happens with videos over a certain bitrate and resolution, regardless of format, webm, ogv, mp4.

Comment: Are you using Chrome and Firefox in Mac or PC? What do you mean by 'buggy' I dont have Safari so I am not sure what the intended result should be. I assume is each scroll is supposed to do 1 frame of the video?

Comment: in Safary for windows it doesn't do anything... What is the intended behavior?

Comment: The intended behaviour is for the currentTime of the video to advance based on the scrollbar position.

Admittedly I haven't tested this on a PC and it's only at an early stage of development, however there seems to be a cutoff point between smooth scrolling of currentTime and choppy scrolling based on the size of the video

Comment: Tested with a different approach, same issue. Every once in a while (typically when the browser has just been restarted), it would work decently for a little while. Then drops frames like crazy. There's definitely something preventing Chrome to work smoothly when scrolling to play videos.

Comment: Response to an old question, but check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51371160/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-make-an-html5-webm-video-scroll-smoothly/51661764#51661764 for how to encode smooth scrolling video.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today, and "solved" it by lowering the precision of the value given to currentTime:

```
vid.currentTime = parseFloat(value).toPrecision(3);
```

For some reason, it went from consistently freezing in Chrome to smooth playback.